# How to set context path in Tomcat 8 for link and script tags

Tags: tomcat8

I have a web-site that I have deployed locally on IIS/ColdFusion but Tomcat/Lucee in production (the production server is Windows Server).  Tomcat is not running as a Windows Service

I am trying to set up virtual directories since IIS and Tomcat seem to handle relative paths differently.  I have a virtual directory called "/style" set in IIS that points to my style sheet directory which works just fine.  When I try to modify the server.xml file in Tomcat8, it never works.

I am using the following  tag in my cfm header file:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="/style/styles.css">
```

Here is a portion of my server.xml file:

```
<Host name="127.0.0.1"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

<context path="/style"  docBase="C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\mysite\_style" ></context>
```

I have tried moving the context to different locations within the server.xml file, I have tried different context attributes.  Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I used the information from the following link:

https://www.petefreitag.com/item/867.cfm

and used the following:

```
<Context path=""
   docBase="C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\ROOT"
   WorkDir="C:\lucee\tomcat\temp">
   <Resources>
      <PreResources base="C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\mysite\_style"
        className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
        webAppMount="/mysite/style"/>
   </Resources>
</Context>
```